# Get two previous and two next products as related products in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, related-products

How do I get two products that were added just before current product and two products that were added just after the current product in a same category as the related product?

Here is how I am fetching 4 related products from the same category in product view page. Right now it shows them in random order.

```
<?php
if ($_product) {
    $categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection()
        ->setPage(1, 1)
        ->load();
    if ($categories->count()) { ?>
        <h2>Related Products:</h2>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $_category) {
            $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
            ?>
            <?php $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image');
            $products->getSelect()->limit(4);
            $products->getSelect()->order('rand()');

            foreach ($products as $productModel) {
                $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productModel->getId());
                $width = 200;
                $height = 150;
                $_imageUrl = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($productModel, 'small_image')->resize($width, $height);
                ?>
                <div class="related-item">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200, 100); ?>" width="200" height="150" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"/>
                    </a>
                    <h4><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h4>
                </div>
            <?php }
        } ?>
    <?php }
}?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Related products are already available as selection in magneto for each products. use that functionality.

Comment: how you define `added just before` and `added just after` ? by date ? by id

Comment: if you have both upper and lower limit for above criteria you can do with taking 2 separate collection with limit of 2 for each. and marge both collection to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be logically implemented like below

- Find category of current product
- Get 2 products of category whose ID is **greater** than current product ID
- Get 2 products of category whose ID is **lower** than current product ID

The code implementation of this should be quick. Give it a try.